# Rewrite an expression as a sum of $SU(2)$ characters?

Tags: polynomials, group-theory

I have an expression of the form

$$q^{-3/2} t^{-7/2}[4qt^2(t + q t^2) + t^2 (q + t) (1 + q t (1 + q t))],$$

I can factor it and write it as

$4((qt)^{1/2} + (qt)^{-1/2}) + (qt+1 + (qt)^{-1})((\frac{q}{t})^{1/2} + (\frac{q}{t})^{-1/2}),$

and conclude that it has content $4(1/2,0)\oplus(1,1/2),$ in terms of $SU(2)$ representations.

Assuming $f(t,q)$ has the form in which such a rewriting is possible, I want it to express it in the form

$\sum_{j_L, j_R}N^{(j_L, j_R)}((qt)^{j_L}+ (qt)^{j_L - 1} + \dots (qt)^{-j_L})((q/t)^{j_R} + \dots + (q/t)^{-j_R}),$ where $(j_L, j_R)$ are half integers or integers.

For those of you familiar with representation theory, I want to express this as a sum of characters of representations of $SU(2)$.

The rewriting is simple enough to do by hand for easy expressions like above, but I want to do it for longer ones. How can I do it using *Mathematica*?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to pick a basis and then have mathematica write what you have in that basis. Right?

Comment: That's correct. Can you please explain what I should use to implement that in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't see how your second expression is a factored form of your first expression. I am reading them as (first expression) `4 q^(-(1/2)) t^(3/2) (t + 2 q t^2) + t^2 (q + t) (1 + q t (1 + q t))` and (second expression) `4 ((q t)^(1/2) + (q t)^(-(1/2))) + (q t + 1 + (q t)^-1) ((q/t)^(1/2) + (q/t)^(-(1/2)))`.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a couple of typos. Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the sum-of-characters expansion

```
expan[j_] /; j >= 0 && IntegerQ[2 j + 1] :=
  Sum[n[jL, jR] Sum[(q t)^iL, {iL, -jL, jL}] Sum[(q/t)^iR, {iR, -jR, jR}], {jL, 0, j, 1/2}, {jR, 0, j, 1/2}];
```

where `j` is the maximum spin that you want to use.

Define a known expansion to demonstrate how the coefficients in `expan[j]` can be obtained.

```
expr = 4 ((q t)^(1/2) + (q t)^(-(1/2))) + (q t + 1 + (q t)^-1) ((q/t)^(1/2) + (q/t)^(-(1/2)));
```

Expand this expression to make things a bit more challenging.

```
expr2 = expr // Expand // PowerExpand

(* 1/(Sqrt[q] t^(3/2)) + 1/(q^(3/2) Sqrt[t]) + 4/(
  Sqrt[q] Sqrt[t]) + Sqrt[q]/Sqrt[t] + Sqrt[t]/Sqrt[q] + 
  4 Sqrt[q] Sqrt[t] + q^(3/2) Sqrt[t] + Sqrt[q] t^(3/2) *)
```

Fit this expression to an expansion.

```
sol = SolveAlways[(expan[1] == expr2) /. {q -> q2^2, t -> t2^2} // PowerExpand, {q2, t2}]

(* {{n[1/2, 1/2] -> 0, n[1/2, 1] -> 0, n[1/2, 0] -> 4, n[1, 1/2] -> 1, 
  n[0, 1/2] -> 0, n[1, 1] -> 0, n[0, 1] -> 0, n[1, 0] -> 0, n[0, 0] -> 0}} *)
```

The change of variables `{q -> q2^2, t -> t2^2}` and the `PowerExpand` are used to get rid of the half-integer powers, so that `SolveAlways` can easily do its job.

Verify the solution.

```
expr == expan[1] /. sol[[1]]

(* True *)

expr2 == expan[1] /. sol[[1]] // Expand // PowerExpand

(* True *)
```

The same approach also works for the expression at the top of your question.

```
expr0 = q^(-(3/2)) t^(-(7/2)) (4 q t^2 (t + q t^2) + t^2 (q + t) (1 + q t (1 + q t)));

sol0 = SolveAlways[(expan[1] == expr0) /. {q -> q2^2, t -> t2^2} // PowerExpand, {q2, t2}]

(* {{n[1/2, 1/2] -> 0, n[1/2, 1] -> 0, n[1/2, 0] -> 4, n[1, 1/2] -> 1, 
  n[0, 1/2] -> 0, n[1, 1] -> 0, n[0, 1] -> 0, n[1, 0] -> 0, n[0, 0] -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Are the answers supposed to be the same?

Comment: Yes. The second example is the expression at the top of the question. I added it to the end of my answer after its typos were corrected, but it doesn't really demonstrate anything more than what is in the body of my answer.

Comment: This is highly appreciated! I looked at a couple of other expressions and it seems to be working flawlessly.